# combining the same nodes in different columns neo4j

Tags: cypher

I am new to neo4j, i have question. Suppose i have columns with values
    
    `Orig  Term
    f       a
    b       g
    c       c
    f       d
    a       e
    a       f`

`+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    ==> | Orig          | Term          |                              |
    ==> +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    ==> | Node[1]{num:"f"} | Node[0]{num:"a"} | |
    ==> | Node[3]{num:"b"} | Node[2]{num:"g"} | |
    ==> | Node[5]{num:"c"} | Node[4]{num:"h"} | |
    ==> | Node[1]{num:"f"} | Node[6]{num:"d"} | |
    ==> | Node[8]{num:"a"} | Node[7]{num:"e"} | |
    ==> | Node[8]{num:"a"} | Node[9]{num:"d"} |  |
    ==> +------------------------------------------------------------------------+`
if we see Node 8 and node 0 are the same values.idea is to implement like mutual friends. But is there any way where not to have the duplication of the nodes no matter in which column they are. Or in other words to create the multiple relationships while using the same node like node a is related to f,e and node d. AS, my csv data has thousnds of the same values which i dont want to remove. beacuse i want to see the relationships. Thank you in advance .

Answer (score 0):

When you load the data, use `MERGE` to create the nodes by their `num` attribute.  `MERGE` in cypher will create something only if it doesn't already exist.  So the node returned by that will be the old one if it already exists, which will avoid duplicates.

`MERGE` the node individually, and then afterwards **separately** merge the relationship you want.

Comment: Thanks Frobber, I did create the nodes with merge. I always do to avoid the dups, but the problem is the two different column. i create the nodes, while using this command, MERGE (Orig:orig{num:csv.Orig}) similarly for the term as well. so what it is doing here, cypher reads the both column step by step and create the different nodes. any idea how to deal with that when two different columns have the same values. which i showed already above.